# Rails: Can't render error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to render errors messages that arise from model validation but I end up with this error:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Hopefully the provided code with be of assistance... I was able to at least get the pages to load when I used :comment instead of @comment, but then I didn't know how to then render the errors partial because it was a symbol and not an actual object. Now that I have changed it to an instance variable of an object, I get the error.

**Error messages partial**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
     </div>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

---

**Comment form**

```
<%= form_for @comment, url: comments_path do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
   <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x2", placeholder: "Comment on this post..." %>
   <%= f.submit "Comment" %>
```

---

**Post form**

```
<%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
   <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What do you want to say?" %>
   <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    #@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Comment Posted!"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Could not post comment"
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end


  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :user_id, :post_id)
  end
end
```

---

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Posted!"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Post could not be submitted"
        redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Comment: `object: f.object?` this is incorrect i believe. try changing it to for comment: `object: @comment`, post: `object: @post`

Comment: I was able to get it by declaring an @comment variable in my posts#index action because that is where the view is being rendered from

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it by declaring an @comment variable in my posts#index action because that is where the view is being rendered from